# Can Process.WaitForInputIdle() return false?

Tags: .net

I can't see how Process.WaitForInputIdle() can return anything but true or throw an exception, but in [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d7363e2) for that method is stated :

> **Return Value**
>
> Type: System.Boolean
>
> true **if** the associated process has reached an idle state.

That if is confusing me, is that only documentation copy / paste from [overloaded version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcdbkyt4) of for method that have wait parameter or I am not understanding something ?

**UPDATE**

To clarify my question, I am aware how Process.WaitForInputIdle() works, just courious if it can returns false in some conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might be an operating system compatibility problem.  Not sure, I don't have reliable docs for Windows 98 anymore.  The key issue is that it pinvokes the native winapi [WaitForInputIdle() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), passing int.MaxValue (0x7ffffffff) instead of INFINITE (-1).  So this call can actually time-out, after 24.85 days.

This restriction appears in more than one place, the System.Windows.Automation.Provider.WaitForInputIdle(int) method also specifies a maximum value of int.MaxValue.

So yes, if you get false then your program has been asleep for 25 days.  Time to call it quits :)

Answer (score 2):

`WaitForInputIdle()` simply calls `WaitForInputIdle(int milliseconds)`, which in turn calls native `WaitForInputIdle` implemented in User32.dll. [The latter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns `WAIT_TIMEOUT` if the wait was terminated because the time-out interval elapsed, which causes the .NET implementation to return `false`.

**EDIT:** `WaitForInputIdle()` passes 0x7fffffff to `WaitForInputIdle(int milliseconds)`, which is **not** the same as INFINITE (defined as 0xffffffff in WinBase.h). Therefore if a process does not enter idle state in approximately 25 days, then `WaitForInputIdle()` *will* return false.

Comment: And in case of Process.WaitForInputIdle() that time-out interval cannot be elapsed since INFINITE parameter is used, right ?

Answer (score 0):

If you supply the non overload you will wait indefinately until it becomes idle.

If you supply `Process.WaitForInputIdle(0)` you basically are testing the process for idle.

If you supply `Process.WaitForInputIdle(-1)` that is the same as the non overloaded version.

During UI start up there are lots of messages coming in. If you override WndProc in a test app you can see them flowing through.

EDIT:
Seeing as you edited question.

If you Specify the WaitForInputIdle(0 or a non Infinite timeout) (ie testing) and the app isn't idle within that time then you would get a false afaik.